# php echo add extra space

Tags: php, echo, space, extra

Input text :

> Test one two three fourfive

Text is splitted by `preg_split` with additional processing and now result array is:

```
Test one
<span>two</span>
three
<span>four</span>
five
```

When I echo this array in loop I get this:

> Test one **two** three **four** five

Four and five should be displayed together, without space.

In HTML source it looks like so:

```
Test one
<span>two</span>
three
<span>four</span>
five
```

Extra space is added after four.

When I directly write this in HTML

```
Test one <span>two</span> three <span>four</span>five
```

text is echoed correctly. It seems that new line in HTML add extra space. Does someone know what happens here?

Answer (score 3):

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html), newlines are whitespace characters and should be rendered as a space by browsers.

If you want to get rid of the space, use `<pre>` and format your text as needed, or modify your markup so you can left-float "five."

Answer (score 2):

A newline is a space. Remove that and your space disappears.

Comment: I can't remove it, it's echoed in loop.

Comment: Then remove it from your `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove \n from your echo and it should be fine.

Just like OP suggest newline is whitespace too.